# Apache Kafka - How to wait for subscription to finish

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I'm using Kafka 2.1.0 and want to publish a message once the subscription has taken place. Is there a way for the producer to know if a subscription has happened and then publish a message? Otherwise I'd be losing the 1st message every time.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do that. Publishers and subscribers are supposed to be decoupled. When you start the subscription, you can choose to start at the beginning of the topic instead of getting only future messages.

Comment: For that approach would the producer have to publish the message first, then consumers subscribe? Also, how can you choose to subscribe such that you start at the beginning? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#newconsumerconfigs, `auto.offset.reset` states:

> What to do when there is no initial offset in Kafka or if the current
>   offset does not exist any more on the server (e.g. because that data
>   has been deleted):
>
> earliest: automatically reset the offset to the earliest offset
>
> latest: automatically reset the offset to the latest offset
>
> none: throw exception to the consumer if no previous offset is found
>   for the consumer's group
>
> anything else: throw exception to the consumer.

Default value of `auto.offset.reset` is `latest`. To ensure that your consumer doesn't loses out first record, you need to set `auto.offset.reset` to `earliest`.